# How to parse an object variable in eventChannel callback method?

Tags: flutter, dart, hashmap

I am programming a flutter app, in which I have a callback from the native system containing some nfc information. I register the callback via the following line of code:

```dart
eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(_onEvent, onError: _onError);
```

The callback looks like this:

```dart
void _onEvent(Object event) {
    //Receive Event
    print("NFC Event received");

    //Get the Payload
    event['Payload']; //This does not work, it gives an error
  }
```

But how can I parse out the data? I know it contains a field by the name `Payload` however, I cannot access it via `event['Payload']`.

I am very confused, I tried to cast it to another type like this: `Map<String, String> eventMap = Map<String, String>.from(event);` but that didnt work. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong and how I can correctly extract the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I found to parse an event to a Map is the following:
I encoded the variable to a String (but I use `json.encode(event)`instead of `event.toString()`as `encode(event)`returns a valid string.

Then I use this string to construct a map via `json.decode`. All of this is achieved with the flutter native library dart:convert. The complete code looks like this:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
...
void _onEvent(dynamic event) {
    //Receive Event
    print("NFC Event received");

    String str = json.encode(event);
    Map eventMap = json.decode(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without too much information of native part, I suggest 
you can reference this package or fork this https://github.com/akeblom/flutter-nfc-reader
directly 
 
this repo fix some issue of pub.dev and work well in real device

the dart code you need reside in 
 https://github.com/akeblom/flutter-nfc-reader/blob/master/lib/flutter_nfc_reader.dart

```
void _onEvent(dynamic data) {
print("Event");
print(data);
```

}

**Edit add more detail** 
akeblom has add Write NFC capability to IOS, so IOS part should work. please ue this fork https://github.com/akeblom/flutter-nfc-reader 
For IOS MissingPluginException issue, I do not have IOS, I suggest you can ask akeblom 
The data part you mentioned in comments if I do not misunderstand is line 77, please see describe below

In Android part. 
https://github.com/akeblom/flutter-nfc-reader/blob/master/android/src/main/kotlin/it/matteocrippa/flutternfcreader/FlutterNfcReaderPlugin.kt 
line 174, use kotlin mapOf returns a new read-only map with the specified contents and eventSink.success result to Dart

```
if (message != null) {
            val data = mapOf(kId to id, kContent to message, kError to "", kStatus to "read")
            eventSink?.success(data)
        }
```

In https://github.com/akeblom/flutter-nfc-reader/blob/master/lib/flutter_nfc_reader.dart 
line 22, with named constructor

```
 factory NfcData.fromMap(Map data) {
    NfcData result = NfcData(
      id: data['nfcId'],
      content: data['nfcContent'],
      error: data['nfcError'],
      statusMapper: data['nfcStatus'],
    );
```

In line 77, NFC read start and _onEvent(dynamic data) get the data.
stream use this named constructor, and parse data, here with map((result)) transfer to NfcData

```
static Stream<NfcData> get read {
    final resultStream = _channel
        .invokeMethod('NfcRead')
        .asStream()
        .asyncExpand((_) => stream
            .receiveBroadcastStream()
            .map((result) => NfcData.fromMap(result)));
    return resultStream;
```

In https://github.com/akeblom/flutter-nfc-reader/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

line 33, response has transfered to NfCData, so example just use  _nfcData = response;

```
FlutterNfcReader.read.listen((response) {
      setState(() {
        _nfcData = response;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the original plugin, which unfortunately did not work with IOS. The error is also describd on the github page: https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader/issues/37. This is why I chose to implement my own solution.
Concerning your code snippet: I fail to see how I can extract the ```data``` of the event?

Comment: I do not have IOS. did you check link I provided https://github.com/akeblom/flutter-nfc-reader not  github.com/matteocrippa. In akeblom , he add write nfc capability to IOS. so it sould work or you can ask akeblom

Comment: I have add more detail to answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `event.toString()`? It might return a string containing the field you are trying to get, from which you can easily parse the value.

You may also want to try:

```
Class<?> clazz = event.getClass();
Field payload= clazz.getField("Payload"); //Note, this can throw an exception if the field doesn't exist.
String fieldValue = payload.toString();
```

If it isn't returning what you want, you may need to make an interface for the object type, with a get method, or override the toString method to get return the Payload value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. event.toString() does work, but then I have to parse the resulting string which is just the whole message concatenated. I wondered if there was an direct way to get the `Payload` message.